# Plotting map locations from csv-file

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, plot

I have a map of a city and a `.csv`-file containing 700 geographic coordinates pointing to locations within that city.

How can I plot these 700 locations on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Delimited Text Data Source type to point to your CSV file, choose whether or not to have headers, choose the columns for X/Y/Z/M data, and then finally your CRS.

Make use of the Sample Data box to ensure you have the settings correct.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a column in your csv file named *WKT*

For each row, populate the column with: Point (longitude, latitude)

Save file

Add the data to QGIS project by using: *Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...*

Set the Geometry Definition to *Well Known Text* and select *WKT* as the Geometry field and you should be good to go.

*Note: You must select an appropriate CRS! If your data is lat-lon then EPSG:4326 should do the trick, if your data is x-y then try EPSG 3857.

Answer (score 2):

> Tested on QGIS 2.18 and QGIS 3.4

Let's assume there is a *.csv*-file `"data"` with its attributes accordingly, see image below.

[image: csv]

Simply drag&drop it into QGIS, so it can appear in the `'Layers Panel'`, like this

[image: csv_in_qgis]

Then proceed with a `"Virtual Layer"` through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

With the following Query, it is possible to plot locations on the map

```sql
SELECT *, make_point(lat, long)
FROM data
```

In case if you possess the exact CRS, you can adjust the above query with a corresponding EPSG code

```sql
SELECT *, setsrid(make_point(lat, long), 4326)
FROM data
```

Check the output

[image: output]

P.S. QGIS adores UTF-8

---

**References:**

- [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system#Identifier)