# Coordinates with leading zeros ignored in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import, leading-zero

I am using Irish national Grid (EPSG: 29902) with X and Y coordinates. Some coordinates start with leading '0's. Example: X= 081800 Y=339700. When imported in to QGIS, the leading zero of the coordinate is lost and the point is located in the wrong place. Example the X coordinate becomes: 81800 instead of 081800.
Options I have tried:

1. Importing as .txt to avoid missing zeros in .csv files
2. Editing the coordinates in the attributes table in QGIS (3.4) but
   leading zeros disappear once put in.

What can I do to ensure leading zeros recognised and points plotted correctly?

Comment: Welcome to the site.How are you importing your coordinates? Are they in .csv format? If open source, please share link to data.

Comment: Thank you Cory, really appreciate you getting back to me. After 7 hours of trying to solve this myself, I actually think there is a problem with the data source, not QGIS. I see even if you cannot see the leading '0's in the coordinates in QGIS, it still plots them correctly. Its back to the data source to solve the issue. Thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is a *.csv*-file `'points_import'` with *wrong* coordinates accordingly, see image below.

[image: csv]

Simply drag&drop it into QGIS, so it can appear in the `'Layers Panel'`, like this

[image: csv_in_qgis]

Then proceed with a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

With the following Query, it is possible to plot locations based on coordinates (even with leading zeroes) on the map

```sql
SELECT osm_id, fclass, name,
make_point(
  (CASE
    WHEN p.x LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.x, '0')
    ELSE p.x
  END),
  (CASE
    WHEN p.y LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.y, '0')
    ELSE p.y
  END)
),
(CASE
  WHEN p.x LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.x, '0')
  ELSE p.x
END) AS x_new,
(CASE
  WHEN p.y LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.y, '0')
  ELSE p.y
END) AS y_new
FROM "points_import" AS p
```

In case if you possess the exact CRS, you can adjust the above query with a corresponding EPSG code, seems like [EPSG:29902](https://epsg.io/29902).

```sql
SELECT osm_id, fclass, name,
setsrid(make_point(
  (CASE
    WHEN p.x LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.x, '0')
    ELSE p.x
  END),
  (CASE
    WHEN p.y LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.y, '0')
    ELSE p.y
  END)
), 31469),
(CASE
  WHEN p.x LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.x, '0')
  ELSE p.x
END) AS x_new,
(CASE
  WHEN p.y LIKE '0%' THEN LTRIM(p.y, '0')
  ELSE p.y
END) AS y_new
FROM "points_import" AS p
```

Check the output

[image: output]

and the updated attribute table

[image: new_at]

P.S. QGIS adores UTF-8

---

**References:**

- [Plotting map locations contained in .csv file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337017/plotting-map-locations-contained-in-csv-file/337061#337061)
- [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system#Identifier)